# Flowable not emitting when database changes

Tags: android, rx-java2, flowable

In Room Database i have an object (User) with id "1" and my DAO is returning a Flowable of this object. After subscribing I call editUser() function.

```
 @Query ("SELECT * FROM User Where id=:id ")
 Flowable<User> getUser(String id);

 @Update
 void update(User user);
```

I am not getting any call back (onNext or onComplete) whenever i make a change to this User object and update it in DB.

```
 public void editUser() {
       User u = new User();
       u.id="1";
       u.age=45;
       appDB.userModel().update(u);
}

 appDB.userModel().getUser("1").subscribe(new Subscriber<User>() {
  @Override
  public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onSubscribed");
  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(User user) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onNext");
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable t) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Error");
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete() {
    Log.d(TAG,"onComplete");
  }
});
```

Could anyone please explain to me what am i missing here ?

Comment: You have to request from the `Subscription`.

Comment: Have you tried `Flowable<List<User>>` instead? You can also try something like `Flowable<Optional<User>>` although I think that requires guava

Comment: @akarnokd: If i use Subscription.OnNext() , does'nt it mean that i am manually asking for the updates ?

Comment: `Subscriber.onNext` is the receiver of events, it doesn't declare when and how many items you want to receive.

Comment: @akarnokd: There is one overridden onNext()  while subscribing. Could you please tell me how/where exactly should i use Subscriber.onNext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request from the `Subscription`!

```
appDB.userModel().getUser("1").subscribe(new Subscriber<User>() {
  @Override
  public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onSubscribed");
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(User user) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onNext");
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable t) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Error");
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete() {
    Log.d(TAG,"onComplete");
  }
});
```